# How to make a UV layout match a baked texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

I'm new to Blender and have a question that maybe be simple to solve, but I don't figure how.
I have a Suzanne texture and baked it to a cilinder.

Here's the original texture with UV layout:
[image]

Here's the texture after being baked to a cilinder:
[image]

Is possible to automatic make the UV of the monkey match this new texture?
Thanks and sorry for the bad english.